# Problems connecting to an Access database from a Java application

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, netbeans, ucanaccess

I am trying to connect to an existing Access database using UCanAccess from NetBeans IDE 8.2 but am getting an error I can't figure out...

This is the code at this time (pStrFile is the full path to an existing Access file):

```
try {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        String database = "jdbc:ucanaccess:" + pStrFile;
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database);
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is stack trace I'm getting...

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at DevGSLibData01.DevGSLibData01.DoConnect(DevGSLibData01.java:28)
at DevGSLibData01.DevGSLibData01.main(DevGSLibData01.java:18)
```

I have also added all the required libraries in the UCanAccess package:

[image: Included libraries]

Comment: Your code looks correct. Try omitting the `class.forName` statement and using `String database = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + pStrFile;` (notice the two slashes at the end of the URL prefix).

Comment: I implemented the changes you suggested, but still get an error...   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\MyWork\JavaDatabases05\TestDatabase.mdb
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
 at DevGSLibData01.DevGSLibData01.DoConnect(DevGSLibData01.java:28)
 at DevGSLibData01.DevGSLibData01.main(DevGSLibData01.java:17)

Comment: Hmm, okay. Try removing ucanaccess-4.0.1.jar from the Libraries for the project, then add it back in again. (Perhaps the project metadata got confused somehow.)

Comment: Yes, I did that and it worked... Fantastic help!!! Spot on the dot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Despite being listed in the Libraries of the NetBeans project, "ucanaccess-4.0.1.jar" was not found in the build path (classpath) when the application was launched. Removing "ucanaccess-4.0.1.jar" from the project Libraries and re-adding it seems to have solved the problem.